# Jenkins pipeline build parameters order mixed up

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

We have defined Pipelines jobs with parameters, in the build with parameters screen (job_name/build?delay=0sec) they appear as ordered in the pipeline code.
i.e.:

1. Param1
2. Param2
3. Param3

But when we select a build form the job build history (job_name/Build #558) and open the Parameters screen there, they are all jumbled up.
i.e.:

1. Param3
2. Param1
3. Param2

I tried searching for a setting in the Jenkins configurations but couldn't find any.

We also found this only occurs when a pipeline calls another job, to the parameters of the called job.

Can anyone explain how to have the Parameters screen ordered correctly?
Jenkins version 2.238

Comment: Sorry for not answering directly to your question .I found very convenient add a small method at the beginning of my build that lists all parameters and some useful environment variables (and sometimes creates a build artifact with the content) . That makes reading my build very easy. Jenkins parameters area has lots of shady parts so I prefer having a single source of truth built by me.

Comment: Have you found a workaround for this yet?

Comment: Haven't found a way around it yet @s_neenu

Comment: @DanAssael Have you tried referring [link](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-62483). This might help if you are trying to build job from your pipeline itself.

Answer (score 0):

I found this issue has been fixed with
https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-62483.

Upgrade the Jenkins to get the fix for this issue.